# Как эффективно посчитать величину по заданной формуле?

Tags: python, алгоритм, numpy

Пусть есть `numpy array X` размером `(l, d)`. Как я могу с помощью средств `numpy` эффективно посчитать величину `sigma2` по формуле ниже. В моём случае `l = 60000, d = 50`. Изначально я планировал для каждого `i` и `j` считать величину, записывать полученное значение в массив и затем от этого массива посчитать медиану. Однако массив выйдет размером почти `60000 * 60000 = 3 600 000 000` элементов. И как я понимаю, никакой памяти для моего плана не хватит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для неупорядоченного массива медиана считается не менее, чем за N/2 памяти, поэтому по вашей формуле - никак. Что это вообще за величина, неужели в numpy нет встроенной функции, считающей его?

Comment: @EzikBro, если честно, я как раз надеюсь, что такая функция есть. Но я, даже листая документацию в разделе статистики, не смог найти такую

Comment: А откуда вы ее вообще взяли?

Comment: Ещё актуально? Полагаю есть решение в два прохода без памяти под все пары векторов.